# How to program the Distance Between Axis Intervals (Charts)

Tags: vb.net, charts, distance, intervals

I am creating a custom bar chart using VB.NET, I am wondering if there is a way to program the distance between intervals in the y axis. For example if I wanted the distance between points 1 and 2 in the axis to be of a certain length e.g 2cm long and the next interval to be of a certain length e.g 5cm long, is there a way to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ChartArea to be a specific size and then configure the Axis.Interval property

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately Axis.Interval only sets when the intervals are, not how long each interval is.

Comment: If you set the ChartArea size to be 10cm then if there are 10 intervals each interval will be 1cm

Comment: Yes exactly but I want to program each individual interval, if there are 10 intervals, I need to have some that 5cm, some that are 1cm, some that are 6cm etc. It looks like there is no built in feature to do so. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: You could potentially use CustomLabels to plot labels at specific places on the Axis.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.customlabel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No (at least, not easily). The `Axis.Interval` property sets all intervals to be the same size. You would need to subclass `Chart` and override the `OnPaint` method to draw the ticks (and/or grid lines) with different spacings. Not sure offhand if there are ways to have it paint parts of the chart as it normally would, while doing custom painting on other parts...

ETA: It may become slightly easier if you only have 2 intervals to worry about (e.g., the axis line itself, then one line 2 cm up, then another line 5 cm up from that, and no more lines after that). You could probably use the `Axis.Interval` and `Axis.MinorGrid.Interval` properties in that case.

ETA again, since it didn't show up nice in the comments: One thing you could try is to hide all of the ticks and grid lines, and then handle the `OnPaint` event (not override) to just draw lines on top of the chart where needed. Something like this psuedocode

```
private void ChartPaint(object sender, Args e) {
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(figure_out_2cm_above_axis, Color.Black, etc);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(figure_out_5cm_above_line, Color.Black, etc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought so. I have more than 2 intervals therefore the method you mentioned would not be possible. Since it is a custom chart I have hidden the axis tick and gridlines, therefore it's just the axis line that is shown. I needed to program the distance since from value in the axis to the other represented the length of time between the events plotted as axis. Anyhow thanks for your reply.

Comment: One thing you could try is to hide all of the ticks and grid lines, and then handle the `OnPaint` event (not override) to just draw lines on top of the chart where needed. Something like

    private void ChartPaint(object sender, Args e) {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(figure_out_2cm_above_axis, Color.Black, etc);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(figure_out_5cm_above_line, Color.Black, etc);
    }